# How to get a folder's policy using C# and Exchange Web Services Managed API?

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm trying to use Exchange Web Services Managed API and C# to organize emails remotely on an Exchange server. Within a given account, there are some folders, such as Inbox, that have a default policy assigned (i.e. "Assign Policy") that will expire items after 30 days. Other folders in the account have a default policy assigned that will never expire items.

I need to find out what the policy is at the folder level before I process the items...is this possible? I have been unable to find anything in the documentation so far.

Also, if anyone knows how to perform the same task in VBA, I'm sure that will come in handy at some point, as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Policy from the PolicyTag property https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.policytag(v=exchg.80).aspx which will give you the GUID you can resolve using the GetRetentionTags method on the Exchange Service class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.getuserretentionpolicytags?view=exchange-ews-api

You can do the same thing in VBA by posting the RAW SOAP and processing the responses its just a time consuming process through eg really simple example of sending a message in VBA

```html
Sub SendMessage(Subject As String, Recipient As String, Body As String, User As String, Password As String)
   Dim sReq As String
   Dim xmlMethod As String
   Dim XMLreq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
   Dim EWSEndPoint As String
   EWSEndPoint = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"
   sReq = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:t=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"">" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<soap:Header>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:RequestServerVersion Version=""Exchange2010""/>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</soap:Header>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<soap:Body>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<CreateItem MessageDisposition=""SendAndSaveCopy"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"">" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<SavedItemFolderId>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:DistinguishedFolderId Id=""sentitems"" />" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</SavedItemFolderId>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<Items>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:Message>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:ItemClass>IPM.Note</t:ItemClass>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:Subject>" & Subject & "</t:Subject>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:Body BodyType=""Text"">" & Body & "</t:Body>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:ToRecipients>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "  <t:Mailbox>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "       <t:EmailAddress>" & Recipient & "</t:EmailAddress>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "  </t:Mailbox>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</t:ToRecipients>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</t:Message>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</Items>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</CreateItem>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</soap:Body>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "</soap:Envelope>" & vbCrLf
   xmlMethod = "POST"
   XMLreq.Open xmlMethod, EWSEndPoint, False, User, Password
   XMLreq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=""UTF-8"""
   XMLreq.setRequestHeader "Translate", "F"
   XMLreq.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "VBAEWSSender"
   XMLreq.send sReq
   If XMLreq.Status = 200 Then
        ' Message Sent okay
    Else
        ' Something went Wrong
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As Glen reply, You can get the Policy from the PolicyTag property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/policytag

Comment: So, just to confirm, the folder will have a PolicyTag property, correct? Assuming the folder has a PolicyTag property, can it be set to a different value so all files/items in the folder inherit the same policy? For example, the folder has a policy to delete all files/items in the folder after 30 days. I change it to never delete, then move files/items into the folder so all files/items will now never be deleted (unless the folder policy or the individual file/item policy changes).

Comment: Its depends on the Folder, for user created folders you should be able to get/set the FolderPolicy Tag. For Default folders eg The Inbox,SentItem etc if a default policy has been applied by the Administrator though policies then you can't override this. Eg if you can set a policy though Outlook then you can do it through EWS, if you can't through Outlook/OWA then you also won't be able to do it via EWS.